# Width adjustment in table columns in tabular* package

Tags: tabularx

Following code is giving tables with full width

```
\begin{table}[!b]
\processtable{Table title the architecture of the can be roughly sketched
consisting of a bottom sensor layer, a middle network layer, and a top application~layer}
{
\begin{tabular*}
{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llllll@{}}\toprule
\TCH{S.No} & \TCH{Type of  } & \TCH{Algorithm} & \TCH{Problem Type} & \TCH{Integrated} & \TCH{Ref} \\
&\TCH{Learning used}  & \TCH{used} & & \TCH{Method} & \\
\midrule

1&Opposition-Based Learning&OBMA (Opposition-Based Memetic Algorithm), HOBMA (Hybrid- Opposition-Based Memetic Algorithm)&Sorting permutations by reversals&&(Sonccoet.al, 2019)\\
\botrule


\end{tabular*}}

\end{table}
```

I would like to adjust the width of the columns so that the table will be fitted in the page

Comment: tabular* adjust the space between columns. The columns will have their natural width. If you prefer the opposite, use tabularx instead.

Comment: Please tell us how or where the macro called `\processtable` is defined. Same for `\TCH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabular*` adjust the space *between* columns. The columns will have their natural width. If you prefer the opposite, use [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) or [tabulary](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) instead.

**Example 0 - xltabular**

As you asked for in the chat, I include a new example of a multi page tabular using [xltabular](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular), which combines [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable). It is possible to use [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable), too. However, you then need to use `p`-columns, and eventually calculate their width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, xltabular, ragged2e}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}

% Define an X-column where you can give relative width.
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}

\usepackage[english]{babel}  % Better hyphenation

\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{1.25\linewidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{
        @{}
        L{0.3}
        L{0.75}    % Five X-column. Sum of fractions must be 5X.
        L{2.2}
        L{0.75}
        L{0.6} 
        L{0.45}
        @{}
    }

    \caption{The architecture of the can be roughly sketched
consisting of a bottom sensor layer, a middle network layer, and a top application~layer\label{tab:architecture }}\\[\belowcaptionskip]

    \toprule
S.No & Type of Learning used & Algorithm used & Problem Type & Inte\-grated Method & Ref \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \toprule
S.No & Type of Learning used & Algorithm used & Problem Type & Integrated Method & Ref \\
    \midrule
    \endhead

1&Opposi\-tion-Based Learning&OBMA (Opposition-Based Meme\-tic Algorithm), HOBMA (Hybrid- Opposition-Based Memetic Algorithm)&Sorting permutations by reversals&&(Soncco et.al, 2019)\\
2&Opposition-based Learning&IFPA (Improved Flower pollination algorithm)&User Identification in social networks&&(Li et.al, 2019)\\
3&Quasi- Opposition-based Learning&QODE (Quasi Oppositional Differential Evolution)&Predicting intensification of OBL &&(Xu et.al, 2019)\\
4&WOBL (Worst Opposition-based Learning)&IBBOA (Improved Biogeography Based Optimization Algorithm)&Medical image segmentation, clustering optimization&&(Zhang et.al, 2019)\\
5&Opposition-based Learning&CSA (Cine Cosine Algorithm)&Improvement of text of satellite images&&(Singh et.al, 2019)\\
6&Oppositional Global based learning&OGHS (Oppositional Global based Harmony Search)&MOFJSP (Multi-Objective Flexible Job-Shop SchedulingProblems)&&(Jian et.al, 2019)\\
7&MOBL (Modified Opposition-Based Learning)&GWO-HS (Grey Wolf Optimizer based Harmony Search)&Parameter Selection&(GWO) Grey Wolf Optimizer&(Alo\-moush et.al, 2019)\\
8&Opposition-Based Learning&DSLPSO (Dynamic Self Learning Particle Swarm Optimization)&Parameter Estimation for PMSM (Permanent Magnet Synchronous Machines)&&(Liu et.al, 2018)\\
9&Opposition-based Learning.&IPOL-HS (Improved Partial Opposition Learning based Harmony Search)&Package Query Processing&&(Shi et.al, 2018)\\
10&Opposition-Based Learning&MHS (Modified Harmony Search Algorithm)&Reconstruc\-tion of defect profiles in pipelines from MFL (Magnetic Flux Leakage)&&(Li et.al, 2018)\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

**Example 1 - [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, booktabs}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!bh]
\caption{Table title the architecture of the can be roughly sketched
consisting of a bottom sensor layer, a middle network layer, and a top application~layer}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXXXXX@{}}\toprule
S.No & Type of & Algorithm & Problem Type & Integrated & Ref \\
& Learning used  & used & & Method & \\
\midrule

1&Opposition-Based Learning&OBMA (Opposition-Based Memetic Algorithm), HOBMA (Hybrid- Opposition-Based Memetic Algorithm)&Sorting permutations by reversals&&(Soncco et.al, 2019)\\
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 - [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) + fixed width clolumns**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, booktabs}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!bh]
\caption{Table title the architecture of the can be roughly sketched
consisting of a bottom sensor layer, a middle network layer, and a top application~layer}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}wl{15pt}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xp{3cm}XXX@{}}\toprule
S.No & Type of Learning used & Algorithm used & Problem Type & Integrated Method & Ref \\

\midrule

1&Opposition-Based Learning&OBMA (Opposi-tion-Based Meme-tic Algorithm), HOBMA (Hybrid- Opposition-Based Memetic Algorithm)&Sorting permutations by reversals&&(Soncco et.al, 2019)\\
\bottomrule


\end{tabularx}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

**Example 3 - [tabulary](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabulary)**

Also, take a look at tabulary. With one fixed width (wl{15pt)} column and sensible \tymin and \tymax, it works OK:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, tabulary, booktabs}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\setlength{\tymin}{35pt}
\setlength{\tymax}{300pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!bh]
\caption{Table title the architecture of the can be roughly sketched
consisting of a bottom sensor layer, a middle network layer, and a top application~layer}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}wl{15pt}LLLLL@{}}\toprule
S.No & Type of Learning used & Algorithm used & Problem Type & Integrated Method & Ref \\

\midrule

1&Opposition-Based Learning&OBMA (Opposi-tion-Based Meme-tic Algorithm), HOBMA (Hybrid- Opposition-Based Memetic Algorithm)&Sorting permutations by reversals&&(Soncco et.al, 2019)\\
\bottomrule

\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank u it worked

Comment: one more doubt in this can we assign individual column widths

Comment: where shall i use that p{<width>}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105442/discussion-between-suresh-reshu-and-sveinung).

Comment: See update regarding xltabular